# Asp.net localization - override which resx file the page will use

Tags: asp.net, localization, overriding, resx, resourcemanager

Trying to sort of combine themes and localization... what i am doing:

Localizing A.aspx, creates:

- App_Localresources\a.aspx.resx
- App_Localresources\a.aspx.resx.fr
  ...

However, i want to add more options. I want to have:

- App_Localresources\a_theme1.aspx.resx
- App_Localresources\a_theme1.aspx.resx.fr
- App_Localresources\a_theme2.aspx.resx
- App_Localresources\a_theme2.aspx.resx.fr

So if i am in Theme1, i want theme 1 set of resources to be used.

**Is there a way i can overrride which resx file A.aspx will use when it loads?**

ie, when it tries to load a.aspx.resx.fr, i want to replace it with a_theme1.resx.fr

Many thanks for any and all ideas! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

[ResourceManager.GetResourceFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourcefilename%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> This method uses CultureInfo 's Name
>   property as part of the file name for
>   all cultures other than the invariant
>   culture. This method does not look in
>   an assembly's manifest or touch the
>   disk, and is used only to construct
>   what a resource file name (suitable
>   for passing to the ResourceReader
>   constructor) or a manifest resource
>   blob name should be.
>
> A derived class can override this
>   method to look for a different
>   extension, such as ".ResX", or a
>   completely different scheme for naming
>   files.

I think that what you want to do is something like this:

```
public class ResxResourceManager : ResourceManager
{  
    protected override string GetResourceFileName(
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return base.GetResourceFileName(culture);       
    }

    public string GetResxFileName(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GetResourceFileName(culture).Replace(".resources", ".resx");
    }
}
```

For more on this:

[Creating a custom Resource Provider](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/#Creating_a_custom_Resource_Provider)

[Under the Hood of BuildManager and Resource Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnet_resxmocking.aspx?display=PrintAll)

Comment: Thanks Leniel! I actually decided to abandon the automatic localization (for a few reasons) to just implement all mapping my self. base class with ResourceManager loding up proper resx files and assigning them to different parts of the screen as needed. Thank you for your suggestion however, looks very interesting!